# How to create function in magento for setSession data and getSession data like setter and getter

Tags: magento-1.8

I need to create function in magento for set session data and getSession data ... I created on e but this is not working ..

```
public function mySession($data){

        $_session = Mage::getModel('core/session');

        $_session->set($data);

        }
```

how can we write session function for set and gat  for custom module

Answer (score 3):

Magento has an excellent system in place for this, really.

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('YourIdentifierHere', $data);`

Optionally, use the magic method:

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setYourIdentifierHere($data);`